# Display the message typed in EditText on a Text View, and then clean the message from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

So how should I write in Java, to display the message typed in EditText on a Text View after I press a button, and then the message in the EditText disappear?

Basically will be how to achieve like chatting app, that I press "Send" button after I type the message and then it displays in the bubbles?

Comment: Dude... you need to do at least minimum research before you come in here asking for soultions, just read litlle bit about the TextViews and EditTexts. Plus there's a billion tutorials of this level on the internet. Off you go now.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just fetch the typed-in text by:

```
String input = editText.getText().toString();
```

Write this String to your text view by:

```
textView.setText(input);
```

And *clean* the editText simply by passing it an empty String:

```
editText.setText("");
```

Comment: clear the text in EditText by :

editText.getText().clear();